# Removing Directories Recursively on Windows 10 Command Prompt

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

How can I delete a directory recursively without prompting to user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I delete a directory recursively without prompting to user?

```
RD /S /Q pathname
```

> `/S`: Delete all files and subfolders in addition to the folder itself.
> Use this to remove an entire folder tree.
>
> `/Q`: Quiet - do not display Y/N confirmation

Source: [RD - Remove Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)

Comment: Thank you! By the way, why I got downvote?